# Creating a generic predicate in Java 8

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, predicate

I'm fairly new to Java 8 and wanted to know if its possible to pass instance methods to another method which in turn calls it on a lambda parameter:

Consider this class:

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class PredicateTest {

    private class SomeType {

        public boolean bar() {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean foo() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        Predicate<SomeType> firstPredicate = someType -> someType.bar();
        Predicate<SomeType> secondPredicate = someType -> someType.foo();
        //...
    }

    public Predicate<SomeType> getGenericPredicate(/* ?? what goes here ?? */) {
        Predicate<SomeType> predicate = someType -> someType./* ?? how to call passed instance method foo or bar? */
        return predicate;
    }
}
```

In `someMethod()` two predicates of `SomeType` are created.

If `SomeType` would have 20 methods it might happen that we need to write 20 similar predicates.

I'm wondering if it is possible with Java 8 to avoid code duplication with a method like `getGenericPredicate` which could take `bar()` or `foo()` as parameter and returns the correct predicate.

The goal would be to refactor `someMethod` to something like this:

```
public void someMethodRefactored() {
        Predicate<SomeType> firstPredicate = getGenericPredicate(SomeType::bar());
        Predicate<SomeType> secondPredicate = getGenericPredicate(SomeType::foo());
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why do you need `getGenericPredicate` since instead of

```
public void someMethodRefactored() {
    Predicate<SomeType> firstPredicate = getGenericPredicate(SomeType::bar());
    Predicate<SomeType> secondPredicate = getGenericPredicate(SomeType::foo());
    //...
}
```

you could simply use

```
public void someMethodRefactored() {
    Predicate<SomeType> firstPredicate = SomeType::bar;
    Predicate<SomeType> secondPredicate = SomeType::foo;
    //...
}
```

---

Assuming that `getGenericPredicate` would actually need to do some additional tasks (logging for instance) you could try with

```
public <T> Predicate<T> getGenericPredicate(Predicate<T> p) {
    //some additional code goes here
    return p;
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
public void someMethodRefactored() {
    Predicate<SomeType> firstPredicate = getGenericPredicate(SomeType::bar);
    Predicate<SomeType> secondPredicate = getGenericPredicate(SomeType::foo);
    //...
}
```

Comment: I would add an short explanation, that an instance method is just a function with the object as first argument and because of that it's usable as you described it.

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of this syntax.

Comment: @Juergen Which syntax you have in mind? It looked like you knew about [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). If you didn't know about `<T>` in `public <T> Predicate<T> getGenericPredicate(Predicate<T> p){...` then you can read more about it in [generic method tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) which is part of official generic tutorial.